# What's the equivalent of URLencode for Redshift?

Tags: redshift

Using Redshift, I need to encode a string before I pass it as a GET string in a URL. Is there an equivalent of `URLencode()` for Redshift SQL?

I am passing data from Redshift to an email marketing program, that will then use the data to form a custom link. I am already doing a number of things to prep the data for the email marketing program as part of my SELECT statement and it would be cleanest if I could prep one field with `URLencode()` as part of the other data prep.

Comment: Can you explain the connection between Redshift (a database) and HTTP GET?

Comment: @mustaccio I have updated my original post with that clarification.